# Enigmatic Naming of Lists in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program in python and I am using a dictionary. I need to create an empty list for each key in the dictionary, and each list needs to have the same name as the key. The keys are user entered, which is why I can't just make a list in the conventional way.
This was the first thing I tried

```
a = {"x":1, "y":2, "z"3}
list(a.keys())
a.pop() = []   # This raises an error
```

I also tried to make the lists when the dictionary was being created, but this did not work either:

```
a = {}
b = input("INPUT1")
c = input("INPUT2")
a[b] = c
b = []
```

This created a list with the name "b" rather than whatever the user entered. Please help!!

Comment: I'm a bit confused.... why don't you just keep the lists in the dictionary? Do you want to create variables with dynamic names? That is bot a good idea anyway.

Comment: Phil: you added a comment to Daniel's answer. I suggest you edit your question and specify what you have and what you want to get, and let us help you by skipping over your (possibly incorrect) assumptions about how.

Answer (score 3):

This really doesn't make much sense. Why do your lists need 'names'? For that matter, what do you mean by 'names'?

Secondly, your code doesn't do anything. `a.keys()` is already a list. Calling `list` on it doesn't do anything else. But in any case, whatever the result of that line is, it is immediately thrown away, as you don't store the result anywhere.

`pop` doesn't work on dictionaries, it works on lists. And what does it mean to set the result of `pop` to a list? Are you trying to dynamically create a set of local variables with the names of each key in the dictionary? If so, why? Why not simply create another dictionary with the keys of the first, and each value as a new list? That can be done in one command:

```
b = dict((k, []) for k in b.keys())
```

(Note that dict.fromkeys() won't work here, as that would cause each element to share the same list.)

Comment: FYI, there is a pop method on dictionaries. But yes, this question makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps I am using the wrong approach. What I am trying to do is write a program that will keep track of a student's grades in all of his courses. The student adds the course and also adds the different segments of the course and how they are weighted, which is why I was using a dictionary. The dictionary might look like this: {"homework": .2, "tests": .8}. Each course might have different weightings or even a different number of segments. So to keep track of the grades I want to make a homework list and a tests list that the student can enter his grades into. @Neves

Answer (score 1):

Use [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead. `input` expects a valid Python expression and WILL evaluate whatever the user inputs. So if the user inputs a word, it'll evaluate that word and try to find an object with its name.

EDIT: for further clarification, `input("INPUT1")` is the equivalent of doing `eval(raw_input("INPUT1"))`, for instance.

Comment: Unless he's using Python 3, where `raw_input` was renamed to `input`.

Comment: Oh, right, I totally forgot that. Since most questions around here tend to be Python 2.x, I just assumed this was the case. :)