# Naming Lists Using User Input

Tags: python, list, input

I would like to let the user define the name of a list to be used in the code, so I have been using an input function. I want the user's response to the input function to become the name of the list. I tried the following:

```
a = input("What would you like the name of the list to be? ")
a = []
```

However, this named the list "a" rather than whatever string the user had responded to the input function. How can I let the user name the list? Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: The reason I want to do this is because I am working on a program to keep track of a student's grades in multiple courses and I want the student to be able to enter different "segments" of the course (such as tests, homework, etc.). Each segment should be an empty list that the student can enter grades into. However, to be able to keep track of different segments throughout the program and to accommodate the fact that different courses have different segments and different numbers of segments, it seemed that user input was the best way to name my lists.

Comment: How is this any different from your previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Letting the User Assign List Names](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117737/letting-the-user-assign-list-names) and/or [Enigmatic naming of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094983/enigmatic-naming-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: All 3 questions are about the same problem I'm trying to solve but haven't yet gotten a solution. This question pinpoints the issue I'm having more effectively than the previous two.

Comment: no need to ask the same question two or three times....that's bothering people and in the end they will ignore you

Comment: @Phil: Please edit your old questions to attract new answers in that case. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to accomplish what you want here is a `dict` of lists:

```
>>> lists = {}
>>> lists['homework'] = [40, 60, 70]
>>> lists['tests'] = [35, 99, 20]
>>> lists
{'tests': [35, 99, 20], 'homework': [40, 60, 70]}
>>>
```

When you can ask for input, the `input` function (`raw_input` in Python 2.x) returns a string, which you can make the key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

A direct answer to your question is that you can use `vars()` to access your variable scope:

```
list_name = input("What would you like the name of the list to be?")
vars()[list_name] = []
```

Then if you enter "foo" at the prompt, you will have a variable named foo.

---

An indirect answer is that, as several other users have told you, you don't want to let the user choose your variable names, you want to be using a dictionary of lists, so that you have all the lists that users have created together in one place.

A program where variable names are chosen at runtime is a program that can never be bug-free. For instance, if the user types "input" into your prompt, you will redefine your input function, so that when that user or another tries to create another list, what you will get instead is an error:

```
>>> list_name = input("What would you like the name of the list to be?")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```